# Changing malloc function allocation space

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is there a way to change where malloc allocate memory space?

For an example, let's say I want malloc to allocate memory within 0x100000 and 0x500000. How can I do this or is there a way for this without changing the malloc implementation?

Comment: What platform? And physical or virtual address?

Comment: Even change the malloc implementation still can't do that,maybe need change system call

Comment: @RichardCritten Virtual address space

Comment: Suspect XY Question - what are you ACTUALLY trying to achieve? Why does heap allocation address matter to you?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - I'm trying to copy memory segment to another process so that the internal pointers and such will be available as same as they were in the original process. I'm trying to find a faster way than serialization/relocation/etc... . FYI.

Comment: Well, then ASK how do to that (hint: `mmap` is your friend)

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot change the behavior of the standard `malloc` call (aside from runtime substitutions such as via [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)), but for some platforms can write your own (separate) memory allocator using specific addresses with the [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) function call.

Answer (score 0):

Using malloc allocates memory on the heap.If your question is related to an embedded software, you can often change the heap start address,size and other parameters in the startup file or linker configuration file.